# How to link LAPACKE to a c++ project using cmake?

Tags: cmake, lapacke

I have installed `liblapacke-dev` and `liblapack-dev`, and use `find_package(LAPACK)` and `target_link_libraries(XXX PUBLIC LAPACK::LAPACK)` to find and link them. However, the compiler complains that it cannot find `LAPACKE_xxx` during the linking process.

Here is a minimum working example:

```cpp
// main.cc
#include "lapacke.h"

int main() {
    LAPACKE_dgbsv(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR,
        1, 1, 1, 1, nullptr, 1, nullptr, nullptr, 1
    );
}
```

```
#CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(test)

set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

find_package(LAPACK REQUIRED)
add_executable(main main.cc)
target_link_libraries(main LAPACK::LAPACK)
```

It seems that I need to find `LAPACKE` instead of `LAPACK`, but the problem is that I did not see any `lapacke-config.cmake` installed. How can I tell the compiler to find and link it?

Comment: "the problem is that I did not see any `lapacke-config.cmake` installed." - Actually, in Ubuntu packages there is no even config file `lapack-config.cmake`. LAPACK search is provided by [FindLAPACK.cmake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindLAPACK.html) module, shipped with CMake. CMake is not shipped with module `FindLAPACKE.cmake`, which could be used for find LAPACKE. You may try obtain such module from somewhere else (e.g. [from here](https://github.com/optimad/bitpit/blob/master/external/LAPACKE/cmake/FindLAPACKE.cmake)) and use it in your project.

Comment: Alternatively, you may build and install LAPACK from [sources](https://github.com/Reference-LAPACK/lapack). That way both config files `lapack-config.cmake` and `lapacke-config.cmake` will be installed, so `find_package(LAPACKE)` will work.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for your reply, that clears things up. I followed the instruction on the git page of lapack and installed it using cmake. However, judging from its output, it only install `lapack-config.cmake` not `lapacke-config.cmake`, is there an option to set?

Comment: Have you enabled LAPACKE option? Otherwise, LAPACKE won't build.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add to your `target_link_libraries` the -llapacke option, like this: `target_link_libraries(main LAPACK::LAPACK -llapacke)`

Otherwise, if you want to be fancier you can use the FindLAPACKE.cmake file that these people created: https://github.com/isl-org/Open3D/blob/master/3rdparty/cmake/FindLAPACKE.cmake

You will need to have a `cmake/` directory within our build directory and append it to your `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` like this:

`set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake" ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})`

Then you can use: `find_package(LAPACKE REQUIRED)` and instead of using `-llapacke` in your `target_link_libraries` you can use `lapacke`